# How to add warning to all uses of native swift function/method?

Tags: swift

standard way of adding warnings is:

```
class someClass {
    #warning("Your warning message") 
    //@available(*, unavailable)
    //@available(*, deprecated, message: "your warning message")
    //@available(*, deprecated, renamed: "new name")
    //@available(swift, introduced: 5)
    func someFuncWithWarning() {}
}
```

but what if I need to add warning to native function of swift?

lets imagine that I need to add warning to `someString.hasSuffix("suffix")` method "Do not use this method"

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: If you are willing to use a linter with custom rules, perhaps that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can.
So, I believe you have only two options

First:

```
protocol Warnings {

    #warning("Your warning message")
    func hasSuffix(_ suffix: String) -> Bool
}

extension String: Warnings {}
```

But in this case warning will not be placed where you call a function. Instead, it will be placed where you used `#warning`.

Second:

If you really don't want anyone to use some function

```
extension String {

    func hasSuffix(_ suffix: String) -> Bool {
        fatalError("Do not use this method")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`#warning` `#error` and `@available` are useful for different reasons:

Both `#error` and `#warning` work in the same way

```
#error ("Your error message")
```

```
warning ("Your warning message")
```

And also work alongside `if` which will trigger only if the condition is true

```
#if os(macOS)
#error("this is not supported on macOS.")
#endif
```

But more importantly, you can use `@available` for deprecated or renamed functions and moreover.

```
@available(*, deprecated, message: "This function is deprecated") func parseData() { }
```

`@available` options

- deprecated
- renamed
- unavailable
- introduced

Comment: this answer is not an answer to the asked question